# pygsheets set_dataframe not being recognized

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, pygsheets

I am trying to write a pandas data frame to a google sheet

```
# open google sheet where 'test' is the name of the project
sh = gc.open_all('test')

# update the first sheet with df, starting at cell B2 and second sheet with ds
wks = sh[:-1]
wks.set_dataframe(df, (1, 1))
```

every time I run this app I get this error:

```
wks.set_dataframe(df, (1, 1))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_dataframe'
```

It seems as if set_dataframe is not being recognized within pygsheets

Has anyone encountered this error or know what is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to debug the value of `wks`?

Comment: You have a simple typo: instead of accessing an index, you perform a list copy using slice notation: compare `somelist[1]`, `somelist[:1]`, and `somelist[1:]`

Answer (score 1):

use **gspread_dataframe**

you can check it out from here [gspread-dataframe](https://github.com/robin900/gspread-dataframe)